# Writing Batch file that monitors a certain web page's status

Tags: batch-file, cmd

**The issue**

I am trying to create a batch file that will execute the following two commands:

```
cd /some/path

dotnet run
```

that produces the following output:

[image: Output]

It starts my localhost server.

**Trying To Accomplish**

What I would like to do is, put those two commands in a batch file and automatically open Chrome to the server address, HOWEVER, the dotnet command takes some time to finish. So somehow, I would have to keep monitoring localhost to see if it is available.

Any help would be appreciated. Although opening a CMD window, typing those 2 commands, and waiting a minute isn't all that much of a problem, it sure would be nice to just click on a batch file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a batch file like this code :

```bat
@echo off
Set "ApplicationPath=%UserProfile%\source\repos\PruttPos\PruttPosSystem\"
CD /D "%ApplicationPath%"
dotnet run
Start "Chrome" Chrome.exe "http://localhost:5000"
pause
```

Comment: Hey Hackoo, thank for that. It appears to start the server, but it doesn't open the web page in Chrome, which is really what I was going for.  A one click solution to start server, and open the page in Chrome. Any idea how to do that?